# Using v-tooltip: directive activation inside a v-html content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-tooltip

I need a help with a Vue.js package, v-tooltip (https://akryum.github.io/v-tooltip/#/).

I read the docs and see the examples on the site, and my test work perfectly:

```
<a
  href="#"
  v-tooltip="{
    content: 'Tooltip Content',
    placement: 'top-center',
    delay: {
      show: 400,
      hide: 400,
    },
  }"
  class="tooltip-link">tooltip special link</a>
```

Now, in my site I can't insert HTML markup like this example, but in my component I get an attribute **data-content**. This attribute is a containing HTML markup with the **v-tooltip** directive, so I print it in this way:

```
<div class="rte general-typo"v-html="content"></div>
```

The *content* is created with a WISIWIG editor, modified to add custom markup for the tooltip element; my vue component just get this string variable.

The results of this operation is that the **v-tooptip** directive is not "read", and the tooltip doesn't show.
With the inspector, I can see the difference between the 2 examples: in the fist case I can see `<a data-v-00f96b30="" href="#" class="tooltip-link has-tooltip" data-original-title="null">tooltip special link</a>` (v-tooltip directive processed, tooltip activated), in the second example I can see `<div data-v-00f96b30="" class="rte general-typo"><a href="#" v-tooltip="{content: 'Tooltip Content',placement: 'top-center',delay: {show: 400,hide: 400,},}" class="tooltip-link">tooltip special link</a></div>` .

How can I "force" the activation of my directive?

Comment: i  dont understand the need for your approach. why cant you use the directive like it is intended?

Comment: If You are trying to add a v-tooltip directive to the content displayed by v-html - it's not a good idea. Put v-tooltip on the .general-typo div alongwith the v-html directive. You can pass any dynamic content to the tooltip inside its config object.